# Simple command to build my Unity project for android via command line

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

What is the right command to build a Unity project as an Android apk?

Using this command I'm able to compile for Windows:

```
"C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.29f1\Editor\Unity.exe" 
  -batchmode 
  -nographics  
  -projectPath "C:\Users\MyUser\MyGitRepo\MyUnityProject" 
  -buildWindowsPlayer "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\MyGame.exe" 
  -logFile 
  "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\build.log" 
  -quit
```

(This is a one line command)

However now I want to do the same for Android. What to I need to change?

```
-buildAndroidPlayer
```

did not work for me...

**Update**
[This website](https://docs.unity.cn/560/Documentation/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html) has an overview of command line options. There are options for anything but Android
(eg `-buildOSX64Player <pathname>` etc). I can
specify `-buildTarget <name>` where  would be android. But I still dont get any apk. Also it does not say to specify an output path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was no simple command for me. I had to add a Build Script that specifies all scenes which are part of the game. The script has to be placed under "Assets/Editor" in order to be accessible from commandline:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class BuildScript 
{
    static void PerformBuild()
    {
        string[] defaultScene = { 
            "Assets/MyGame/Scenes/MyGame_TitleScene.unity",
            "Assets/MyGame/Scenes/MyGame_MainScene.unity",
            "Assets/MyGame/Scenes/MyGame_EpisodeScene.unity",
            };

        BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(defaultScene, "MyGame.apk" ,
            BuildTarget.Android, BuildOptions.None);
    }

}
```

and build using

```
"C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.29f1\Editor\Unity.exe" -projectPath "path\to\my\Game" -executeMethod BuildScript.PerformBuild -logFile "MyGame\APKs\build.log"
```

Comment: I ran the command using the script you provided but it gave me errors 1. `The name 'BuildPipeline' does not exist in the current context` 2. `The name 'BuildTarget' does not exist in the current context` 3.  `The name 'BuildOptions' does not exist in the current context`. Any idea how to resolve those?

Comment: nevermind, got the mistake. Thanks for the script.

Comment: @aquaman [The BuildScript Class needs to be in the Assets/Editor folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74461108/5211833), according to a comment-posted-as-answer on this post.