# Github actions Unity toy example running on Windows VM

Tags: unity-game-engine, continuous-integration, github-actions

I've found a website ([game.ci](https://game.ci/docs/github/test-runner)) that shows an example for running Github action workflows for building and testing Unity games.

However, the toy example that I can find only runs on a Ubuntu VM ("ubuntu-latest").

I need a similar file for a Windows VM. Can anybody help me?

**Context:**

This is what my current .github/workflow script for an Ubuntu VM looks like:

```
name: Test

on:
  workflow_dispatch: {}

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build my project ✨
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      # Checkout
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          lfs: true

      # Cache
      - uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: MyGame/Library
          key: MyGame/Library-${{ hashFiles('Assets/**', 'Packages/**', 'ProjectSettings/**') }}
          restore-keys: |
            Library-

      # Test
      - name: Run tests
        uses: game-ci/unity-test-runner@v2
        env:
          UNITY_LICENSE: ${{ secrets.UNITY_LICENSE }}
        with:
          projectPath: MyGame/
          githubToken: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      # Build
      - name: Build project
        uses: game-ci/unity-builder@v2
        env:
          UNITY_LICENSE: ${{ secrets.UNITY_LICENSE }}
          UNITY_EMAIL: ${{ secrets.UNITY_EMAIL }}
          UNITY_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.UNITY_PASSWORD }}
        with:
          projectPath: MyGame/
          targetPlatform: Android

      # Output
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          projectPath: MyGame/
          name: Build
          path: build
```

- On the game.ci website there is only a [Windows example for Gitlab](https://game.ci/docs/docker/windows-docker-images) but not for Github.
- I've also found a windows based github actions Unity workflow in a [foreign project](https://github.com/homuler/MediaPipeUnityPlugin/blob/master/.github/workflows/windows-test.yml). However I'm not able to adapt it to my case. Apart from using a docker container by "[crazy-max](https://github.com/crazy-max/ghaction-chocolatey)" the Github Actions file uses a secret called "secrets.UNITY_TOTP_KEY" which I'm not sure about what to fill in there...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a first draft of a toy solution that I could run successfully on a Dummy Unity project.

Prerequisites:

- Create a [BuildScript.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68774165/2191652) to specify build scenes and target platform
- Enable 2 factor authentication in your unity account

  - read out starting code manually -> enter as secret to your respective github repository ("UNITY_TOTP_KEY")
- Create PlayMode tests using Unity's "Automated QA" (otherwise comment that part or change to "EditorMode")

```
name: Run Tests on Windows
on:
  workflow_call:
    secrets:
      UNITY_EMAIL:
        required: true
      UNITY_PASSWORD:
        required: true
      UNITY_TOTP_KEY:
        required: true
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        # Specify path of Unity project relative to repository root
        projectPath:
          - ./  
        os:
          - windows-2019
        unity:
          - { version: "2020.3.36f1", changeset: "71f96b79b9f0" }
    steps:
      
      # Install UnityHub
      - name: Install UnityHub
        uses: crazy-max/ghaction-chocolatey@v2
        with:
          args: install unity-hub -y
      
      # Install UnityEditor
      - name: Install UnityEditor
        run: |
          Start-Process -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru "C:\Program Files\Unity Hub\Unity Hub.exe" -ArgumentList "-- --headless install --version ${{ matrix.unity.version }} --changeset ${{ matrix.unity.changeset }}"
          exit 0

      # Generate license activation file
      - name: Generate a license activation file
        run: |
          Start-Process -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\${{ matrix.unity.version }}\Editor\Unity.exe" -ArgumentList "-quit -batchmode -createManualActivationFile -logfile"
          exit 0

      # Request Unity license 
      - name: Request a Unity license file
        env:
          UNITY_EMAIL: ${{ secrets.UNITY_EMAIL }}
          UNITY_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.UNITY_PASSWORD }}
          UNITY_TOTP_KEY: ${{ secrets.UNITY_TOTP_KEY }}
        continue-on-error: true        # Add this line to get pass the error flag
        run: |
          npm install -g unity-verify-code
          git clone -b ci https://github.com/homuler/unity-license-activate.git
          cd unity-license-activate
          npm install
          cd ..
          npm install -g ./unity-license-activate
          unity-license-activate "$env:UNITY_EMAIL" "$env:UNITY_PASSWORD" Unity_v${{ matrix.unity.version }}.alf --authenticator-key "$env:UNITY_TOTP_KEY"
      
      # # Upload a screenshot (uncomment in case of error in previous step)
      # - name:  Upload error screenshot
      #   uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
      #   with:
      #     name: screenshot_error
      #     path: error.png

      # Use license to activate Unity editor     
      - name: Activate License
        run: |
          $ulf_file = Get-Item Unity_*.ulf
          $process = Start-Process -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\${{ matrix.unity.version }}\Editor\Unity.exe" -ArgumentList "-batchmode -nographics -logFile -quit -manualLicenseFile $ulf_file"

          if ($process.ExitCode -ne 1)
          {
            exit $process.ExitCode
          }

      # Checkout source code
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
          lfs: true

      # Cache Library folder
      - name: Cache Library folder
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ${{ matrix.projectPath }}/Library
          key:
            Library-${{ matrix.projectPath }}-${{ matrix.targetPlatform }}-${{
            hashFiles(matrix.projectPath) }}
          restore-keys: |
            Library-${{ matrix.projectPath }}-${{ matrix.targetPlatform }}-
            Library-${{ matrix.projectPath }}-
            Library-

      # Run Play Mode Tests
      - name: Run play mode tests
        env:
          ARTIFACTS_PATH: testResults
        run: |
          $process = Start-Process -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\${{ matrix.unity.version }}\Editor\Unity.exe" `
            -ArgumentList `
            "-batchmode -nographics `
            -logFile `
            -projectPath ${{ matrix.projectPath }} `
            -testResults $env:ARTIFACTS_PATH/results.xml `
            -runTests `
            -testPlatform PlayMode `
            -testCategory !GpuOnly;!SignalAbort"
          cat ${{ matrix.projectPath }}/$env:ARTIFACTS_PATH/results.xml
          exit $process.ExitCode
        # Arguments explained:
        # - If using '!MyCategory' then no tests with the 'MyCategory' category will be included in the run

      # Upload Test results
      - name: Upload test results
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        if: always()
        with:
          name: Test results for ${{ matrix.unity.version }} on ${{ matrix.os }}
          path: ${{ matrix.projectPath }}\testResults

      # Build
      # target platform is specified in "Assets/Editor/Scenes/BuildScript.cs"
      - name: Build apk
        env:
          ARTIFACTS_PATH: APKs
        run: |
          mkdir $env:ARTIFACTS_PATH
          $process = Start-Process -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\${{ matrix.unity.version }}\Editor\Unity.exe" `
            -ArgumentList `
            "-batchmode -nographics `
            -logFile $env:ARTIFACTS_PATH/build.log `
            -projectPath ${{ matrix.projectPath }} `
            -executeMethod BuildScript.PerformBuild" 
          cat ${{ matrix.projectPath }}\$env:ARTIFACTS_PATH\build.log
          exit $process.ExitCode

      # Upload apk to Github actions
      - name: Upload apk to Github actions
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: APKs
          path: APKs
```

The gist of this script came from [here](https://github.com/homuler/unity-license-activate) (and I had to use a hack since I'm not from the US)

Issues:

- Cache directories seem not to work (probably due to bad naming)
- Play mode tests are all failing. This seems to be due to the options "-batchmode -nographics" when running the tests. However, omitting these options causes the tests to run successfully on my local Windows machine but to run indefinitely on github (had to cancel them manually)