# Unity: How to revert Player BuildSettings from command line

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using a build script to build my Unity project from command line. However, every time I build an .aab file (android app bundle for upload in Play Store). The following checkbox is getting marked inside the Editor Build Settings:

[image]

However, when I want to do the next build (not for Play Store), that check box is still checked.
How to undo this checkbox from command line?

more context:

- the problem is that this change in the build settings does not appear as a change in the files tracked by git (e.g. ProjectSettings.asset), so I cannot simply do `git reset --hard` to remove that

Comment: because according to their docs that setting IS how you make it produce aab not apk

Comment: I specified the question a little more clearly. I need a way to undo this checkbox from code / command line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use a [post process](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Callbacks.PostProcessBuildAttribute.html) script to revert the settings.

```
public class MyPostProcess
{
    [PostProcessBuild(999)]
    public static void OnPostProcess(BuildTarget target, string path)
    {
        EditorUserBuildSettings.buildAppBundle = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks interesting. Could you explain a little how to use this class? Right now I'm using a BuildScript class to build my Project. As described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68774165/2191652

Comment: Just add it to your project, the method will be automatically called after building the player.

Comment: Oh, you are using `-executeMethod`, so how about add `EditorUserBuildSettings.buildAppBundle = false` to the end of the method?